# Strange behaviour with mosfets

Tags: mosfet

I was doing some experiments with mosfets I have at home. Everything works but there's something I can't really explain yet.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpz2U3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The schematic is quite basic, the gate is connected to a dangling wire and I connect it manually to positive current to open the gate.

The load I have is a DC motor.

When the gate is connected to V+, the motor turns, when I disconnect the gate goes back to gnd and the motor stops.

The strange moment is that when the gate is to ground, the scope displays some kind of sine/triangle wave. The motor doesn't turn. I guess I'm sensing a voltage because the MOSFET allow a very very small amount of current to leak from the source to the drain.

My power source is of 7v and the voltage on the scope goes from 0v to 10v when the gate is closed. The frequency of the wave is of 100hz. I don't think it's AC noise because it should be of 60hz and go below 0v and probably not as high as 10v.

Is it normal to see something else than 0v when the gate is connected to ground? I was expecting to see maybe a really low voltage as I read that MOSFETs would behave like power resistor when the gate isn't completely open.

Comment: I removed the [tag:npn] tag. You're not dealing with an NPN transistor here, or am I missing something?

Comment: Gates are control pins and are neither open nor closed. The drain-source channel can be regarded as being open-circuit or closed (like a relay contact) as a first approximation. Your question is unclear in that respect and it's unclear where your scope is connected.

Comment: Does your motor have a internal free wheeling diode or is it missing?

Comment: @Andyaka the scope is connected as explained on the schematic with Osc+ and Osc gnd. What's not clear?

Comment: @Humpawumpa it's a dc brushed motor.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ah right, didn't see the npn tag was only for bjts It's still a NPN mosfets

Comment: But your scope is connected across the 7 volt power supply.

Comment: "NPN" is a bipolar transistor type. Do you maybe confuse n-Channel with it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller probably, Mouser seems to put the N-Channel,NPN on transistor polarity for mosfets too.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix that might be a leftover from former categorizations, maybe they had FETs and BJTs in the same category (why PNP is not a MOSFET type: PNP implies *junctions between P- and N-doped regions*, a FET doesn't have that junction-triple)

Comment: @Andyaka Ah right! that's probably it. The way I connected my scope, it was probably using the scope as a path. I moved the gnd node to measure around the motor and as expected I see 0v  without any fluctuation.

Comment: @Loïc, even a DC motor needs a commutation path. Only question is whether your motor already has an internal free-wheeling diode or not.